# A finite subset of a metric space is closed

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I need to prove that a finite set of points $\{a_1,a_2,\dots ,a_n\}$ in a metric space is a closed set. Can it be assumed that $\{a_i\}$ is a closed set in $X$ so that $ X$ would be the finite union of closed sets?

Comment: Depending on your definition of closed, it may be completely obvious (e.g. $\{a_i\}$ certainly contains all its limit points). Either way, you should give a (short) proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that its compliment is open: if $x \in X\setminus \{a_i\}$ then $d(x, a_i) = k\gt 0$. Can you find an open ball in $X\setminus\{a_i\}$ that contains $x$

Comment: Is {ai} always closed in X. In the book I am using it states that {a} is open in $\R\$ using the discrete metric

Comment: $\{a_i\}$ is always closed in a metric space (more generally in a Hausdorff topological space). It will also be open if we use the discrete metric (with the discrete metric *every* set is open), but that isn't a problem. A set can be both open and closed.

Comment: how do you know that closed balls a closed sets? That needs a proof, and it would be easier to prove directly that a point is a closed set. Take a point $p$,prove that its complement is open, indeed take any $x$ in the complement, look at the _open_ ball $B(x,d(x,p))$.

Comment: ok thanks that helped a lot